# Jquery - Dialogue not displaying correctly on IE6

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am trying to use bgiform but it seems to have no effect. The text in IE is pushed off of the screen of the dialogue box when its displayed. It works fine in FF. Any ideas?

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Zoleris</title>
<link href="style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="jquery-ui-themeroller/theme/ui.theme.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-1.3.1.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="bgiframe_2.1.1/jquery.bgiframe.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery-ui-personalized-1.5.3.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">                                         
  $(document).ready(
  function()
  {
    $("#block").dialog({
    bgiframe: true});
  }
  );
 </script>
<style>
#block {
    width: 150px;
    height: 70px;
    margin: 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div id="block" title="title">blah</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

This [library](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/bgiframe) are outdated , it is tagged as `Metaplugin`

`Metaplugins` have the following characteristics:

- you could implement yourself with
  jQuery
- **it can be difficult to implement across browsers**
- users
  won't notice them

see the [Release notes](http://plugins.jquery.com/node/250)

> Now it works with jQuery **1.1.3**

I suggest you to see for other plugin like this.